# Custom stock status option for simple and variable product in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, stock

I would like to add a new stock status when uploading a product in woocommerce. I found a solution in stackoverflow but that has the option only in simple product. How can I get the custom status for variable product also?

Comment: Have you tried any plugins for custom stock statuses? What's the code you've tried, or at least the link to the other SO question?

Comment: No i havent found any plugin